# Lightbox not working on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, plugins, lightbox

I am unable to get the [Lightbox Plus Colorbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/lightbox-plus/) plugin to work on a wordpress theme that I am creating. I followed the steps to install the plugin -

1. Extract lightbox-plus.zip to your wp-content/plugins directory.
2. In the admin panel under plugins activate Lightbox Plus ColorBox.
3. In the admin panel under Appearance click on Lightbox Plus ColorBox to configure to your taste.
4. It should now be completely set up and functional

However, it is not functional. When I click on an image in a post, it takes the viewer to a new page. I'm completely stumped. My javascript is pretty weak and I'd love any help I can get to make this work!

```
<div style="background-color:#383838; padding:15px 0px; width:auto;">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <div class="entry">
        <h2 class="background_header"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>          
    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

it is probably because you don't have the rel="lightbox[id|name]" to your img links.

In your theme, add this to your functions.php file.

to add the ID and separate them

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_lightbox_rel');
function add_lightbox_rel( $content ) {
       global $post;
       $get_img ="/<a(.*?)href=('|\")(.*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)('|\")(.*?)>/i";
       $img_replace = '<a$1href=$2$3.$4$5 rel="lightbox['.$post->ID.']" title="'.$post->post_title.'"$6>';
       $content = preg_replace($get_img, $img_replace, $content);
       return $content;
}
```

Comment: hi @robert lee, i did that and it didn't do anything. the image is just opening in a second page

Comment: can you reference a site so that we can look and see if there is something else that is wrong?  is the rel= showing up on all the images?  there are many factors to consider..